# How to program a differential equation of form dy/dt = f(t,y) (i.e. time is in differential equation) in R?

Tags: r, time, ode, differential-equations

I am trying to simulate a model with this differential equation for concentration A:

```
dA/dt = (a-b)*exp^(d*(s-t))
```

(The equations has parameters: a, b, d, and s.) I can not figure out how to use R to solve differential equations that have a t (time step) variable? I tried it with the function radau of the package deSolve (See beneath). I did not get the code to work. I also do not understand how to define the index variable? Or if this is solvable with this function at all? (All my other simpler differential equations I have ran in the past with the ode function of deSolve, worked fine).

I hope you can help me!

**My try:**

```
#Defining parameters
parameter <- c(a=0.03, b=0.02, d=0.01, s=179)

#Defining Function
Function1 <- function(t, y, parameter) { with (as.list(Y),
list(c(dA = (a-b)*exp^(d*(s-t)))))}

#Initial conditions
yini <- c(A=1)

#Mass matrix
M <- diag(nrow=1)
M[5,5] <- 0
M

#index/times/output
index <- c(1)
times <- seq(from = 0, to = 10, by = 0.01)
out <- radau(y = yini, func = Function1, parms = parameters, times = times, mass = M, nind = index)
plot(out, type = "l", lwd = 2)
```

Comment: "I did not get the code to work" Did you get an error message? What output were you expecting?

Comment: Does the suggestion below from [David Foster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8103477/david-foster) help? Change your `as.list(Y)` to `as.list(y)`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's up with `M` or `index` as they don't appear in your model, but here's code that runs and produces results based on your code.

```
#Defining parameters
parameter <- c(a=0.03, b=0.02, d=0.01, s=179)

#Defining Function
model <- function(t, y, parameter) { 
  with(as.list(parameter),{                              
        dA  <-  (a - b) * exp(d * (s - t))
        list(dA)
        })
}

#Initial conditions
yini <- 1

# Output times
times <- seq(from = 0, to = 10, by = 0.01)

# Solve model
out <- ode(y = yini, func = model, parms = parameter, times = times)

# Plot results
plot(out, type = "l", lwd = 2)
```